# How to create a long run program

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a formula, likely used in Google Sheets, that will count the number of consecutive "hits" forward from the first recorded event and then another that will count in reverse from the last recorded event.

Example

X X X X X X X X O X

In this example, the consecutive hits forward would be "8" and the consecutive hits in reverse would be "1"

I have been unsuccessful in coming up with a formula

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=LEN(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ), "O"))
```

and

```
=INDEX(LEN(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ), "O")),,COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, "O")))
```

[image]